# MediaPlayer State Just After Finished Song

Tags: android, eclipse, media-player

Given the diagram http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#Valid_and_Invalid_States when the mediaplayer object is playing and then stops playing (because song finished ofc), does it enter the stopped state or is it still in started? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote from the link you shared:

> When the playback reaches the end of stream, the playback completes.
>
> If the looping mode was being set to `true` with `setLooping(boolean)`, the MediaPlayer object shall remain in the Started state.
>
> If the looping mode was set to `false` , the player engine calls a user supplied callback method, `OnCompletion.onCompletion()`, if a `OnCompletionListener` is registered beforehand via `setOnCompletionListener(OnCompletionListener)`. The invoke of the callback signals that the object is now in the `PlaybackCompleted` state.
>
> While in the `PlaybackCompleted` state, calling `start()` can restart the playback from the beginning of the audio/video source.

So it enters PlaybackCompletedState and then stop state after playback is completed. If looping is set to true, it remains in started state.